# Hölder norm bounded by $L^p-$norm?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $C_0^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$, $0<\alpha<1$ denote the space of Hölder-continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support.

Is it true that for any $f\in C_b^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$ one has $\| f\|_p \leq C \| f\|_{\alpha}$ for any $p$ maybe strongly depending on $\alpha$?. In other words, are there known embeddings from $C_0^\alpha$ to $L^p$ spaces? If not, are there any counterexamples? I have the feeling its true since $C_0^{\alpha}\hookrightarrow C_0^1 \hookrightarrow L^p$ right? But is there a direct proof of the estimate?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The title should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true if $\mathbb R$ is replaced by a closed interval $[a,b]$. To see that this is not true, take
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{clc}
0 & \text{if} & x\le -2n, \\
\frac{x+2n}{n} & \text{if} & -2n\le x\le -n,  \\
1 & \text{if} & -n\le x \le n, \\
\frac{2n-x}{n} & \text{if} & n\le x\le 2n,  \\
0 & \text{if} & x \ge 2n.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then
$$
\|f_n\|_p>2n\qquad\text{and}\qquad \|f\|_{0,\alpha}=1.
$$

Comment: $f_n$ has compact support but $\lim_n f_n$ does not, so I guess it's still true for compactly supported functions, or defined on an interval as a particular case. Thanks! :)